# How to update existing DB with Identity users and roles in .net core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using the code first pattern to creating DB.  I already have a DbContext/DB setup.  Now I decided to add auth support to it using Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.
I've created another DbContext to have the identity related tables like below :

```
public class AccountDbContext:IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AccountDbContext(DbContextOptions<AccountDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
    }
```

I've added the above DbContext in startup.cs as below :

```
services.AddDbContext<AccountDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TESTDB")));
```

And finally :

```
dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

But since TESTDB is already associated with an existing db context, its already created.  So I guess the function call - EnsureCreated() would do nothing and simply return.

My questions:

1. Is there any way to avoid creating a duplicate context for IdentityContext and somehow add it to my existing DB Context ?
2. If I do go about a separate DbContext like above (but using the same existing DB) how to ensure the Identity/roles tables are auto created ?

Comment: You might be looking for dbcontext.Database.Migrate()

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to create two context by extending the AccountDbContext in your default DbContext.

```
public class YourDbContext : AccountDbContext
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution.  I can directly inherit the IdentityDbContext instead of DbContext (since IdentityDbContext extends DbContext anyway).  Migrations can be added as usual.